# VPS: xy.com working, but www.xy.com not

Tags: dns, vps

I set up a VPS for my project, but I can access it with `myawesomeproject.com`, but I got DNS error with `www.myawesomeproject.com`

My apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/myawesomeproject/public
        ServerName myawesomeproject.com
        ServerAlias www.myawesomeproject.com
        <Directory "/var/www/myawesomeproject/public/">
                AllowOverride All
                Options FollowSymLinks
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myawesomeproject-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

I only have one DNS zone for it at the registrar:

> Type - IP - TLS
>   A - 'MyVPS'sIP' - 3600

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A Record is probably for your naked domain, so that's why the version without WWW is working.

You need to make an A record for the www subdomain pointing to the same IP as the naked domain, or create a CNAME record pointing to the naked domain.

Cheers